# How to call Navigation.PopAsync() from Javascript

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Web View inside Xamarin Forms content where I'm using plain `html div`, I want to navigate to another page (`Navigation.PopAsync` or `Navigation.PushAsync`) on `div` `onClick()`, is it possible without implementing any renderer or hybrid view?

Comment: You need to Implement a HybridWebView to realize it.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [HybridWebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) to realize your function .

HybridWebView.cs:

```
public class HybridWebView : View
{
    Action<string> action;

    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create (
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri {
        get { return (string)GetValue (UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue (UriProperty, value); }
    }

    public void RegisterAction (Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup ()
    {
        action = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAction (string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null) {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke (data);
    }
}
```

Used in **Xaml.cs** :

```
<local:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView" Uri="index.html" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Then in **Android** , Create `HybridWebViewRenderer.cs` :

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
{
    const string JavascriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";
    Context _context;

    public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webView.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient($"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
            Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{Element.Uri}");
        }
    }
}
```

**JavascriptWebViewClient.cs** inside Renderer as follow:

```
public class JavascriptWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    string _javascript;

    public JavascriptWebViewClient(string javascript)
    {
        _javascript = javascript;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
    }
}
```

Also need `JSBridge` to process JavaScript :

```
public class JSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
{
    readonly WeakReference<HybridWebViewRenderer> hybridWebViewRenderer;

    public JSBridge (HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer)
    {
        hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference <HybridWebViewRenderer> (hybridRenderer);
    }

    [JavascriptInterface]
    [Export ("invokeAction")]
    public void InvokeAction (string data)
    {
        HybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer;

        if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget (out hybridRenderer)) 
        {
            hybridRenderer.Element.InvokeAction (data);
        }
    }
}
```

Okey, `index.html` sample as follow :

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<h1>HybridWebView Test</h1>
<br/>
Enter name: <input type="text" id="name">
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:invokeCSCode($('#name').val());">Invoke C# Code</button>
<br/>
<p id="result">Result:</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function log(str)
{
    $('#result').text($('#result').text() + " " + str);
}

function invokeCSCode(data) {
    try {
        log("Sending Data:" + data);
        invokeCSharpAction(data);
    }
    catch (err){
        log(err);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After running it , the view is as follow:

[image]

Last , where we invoke function from JavaScript is in ContenPage:

```
hybridWebView.RegisterAction ( data => { Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageNext()); });
```

The **IOS** `HybridWebViewRenderer.cs` class is as follow :

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WKWebView>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{
    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){window.webkit.messageHandlers.invokeAction.postMessage(data);}";
    WKUserContentController userController;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts ();
            userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler ("invokeAction");
            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup ();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                userController = new WKUserContentController();
                var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
                userController.AddUserScript(script);
                userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "invokeAction");

                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
                var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }

            string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", Element.Uri));
            Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (fileName, false)));
        }
    }

    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage (WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {
        Element.InvokeAction (message.Body.ToString ());
    }
}
```

Here also has a official [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-hybridwebview/) for reference.

Comment: Is there any way passing the content of the html file in a function so that it can be set as page source in run time?

Comment: @3not3 Yeah , it can . You can add property in HybridWebView ,then can pass the content of html .

Comment: If any one finds it helpful, I added another property in `HybridWebView.cs` called `HtmlContent` and used `Control.LoadDataWithBaseURL($"file:///android_asset/Content/{Element.Uri}", Element.HtmlContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)` in Renderer class to load the `Html` content. Point to be noted try keeping html tags the way mention in `index.html`, for example in my case Jquery was not responding if I added `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag.

Comment: @3not3 If `HtmlContent` is a type of `string` , when load url have a try like this :`Control.LoadUrl(xxx.HtmlContent) ;` .

Comment: If I try setting the` htmlcontent` `onAppearing()` method I get an empty view, but works when I set the content inside the constructor. Is there a page load method that I can override in the renderer class that will set the content during the load?

Comment: @3not3 Hi , `onAppearing()` will work , maybe something wrong when passing content to renderer. You should be sure uri path can be displayed successfully first.

Comment: @3not3 You can refer to [this](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-samples/blob/master/RazorTodoADO/RazorTodo.Android/RazorWebViewClient.cs) to check whether url path is correct.